# Ubuntu 16.04 iGPU -> Dedicated GPU -> Screen possible?

Tags: drivers, radeon, hybrid-graphics

Background:
Ubuntu 16.04 AMD binary/fglrx drivers where removed, AMDGPU not supported and open source driver does not really work for my GPU (no ums support in radeon module, followed by a random pattern of colors or a black screen. Did not found any working solution for that except nomodeset which results in software rendering and awful resolution)

CPU: Intel i5-4570 GPU: AMD Radeon HD 7870

I want to use the iGPU for xserver but the video signal should pass though my dedicated GPU to my Screen. (can't be removed, i need it on Windows (dualboot))
How to do that if its possible?

Comment: You might want to read up on Kernel 4.8.7 to see if support for your GPU is available now